# Updating record card in Salesforce One App after redirecting from VF page

Tags: salesforce1-app

I created custom button on record layout with VF page. On VF page we update this record and redirect user back to record (details tab), but to see changes user have to refresh this card manually. There is my code on VF page for updating record and redirecting back to card:

```
    function updateOwner(param) {
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.ControllerPickUp.updateOwner}',
            param,
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    redirect();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    function redirect(){
        if ('{!$User.UITheme}' === 'Theme4t') {
            sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!Lead.Id}', 'detail');
            //sforce.one.back(true);
        } else {
            window.location.href='/' + '{!Lead.Id}';
        }
    }


updateOwner('{!Lead.Id}');
```

Is it possible update record card after redirecting from VF page?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience) having to do with Visualforce+Apex updates failing to invalidate record data that is cached by Lightning pages.

> When data is updated from an Apex controller and redirected to the detail page in Lightning Experience, the updated data is not seen in the UI, even though the data is updated in the database.

I believe the issue you're observing is a manifestation of that issue.

Unfortunately, the recommended workaround is not applicable to your use case here. A genuine fix would probably mean using a mechanism other than Visualforce to perform the record update, such as a Quick Action or a custom Lightning component.